# Forcing instantiation of all of a template classes member functions

Tags: c++, templates, testing, gcc, gcc9

During initial development of a template class, before I've written full test cases, I am finding that I would like the ability to force the compiler to generate the code for every member (including non-static ones) of a template class for a specific set of template parameters, just to make sure all the code at least compiles.

Specifically, I'm using GCC 9 (I don't really need this ability for other compilers, since it's just something I want to temporarily make happen during development); and its `c++14`, `c++17`, `c++2a` and `c++20` standards.

For example, I might write the following code:

```
template <typename D> struct test_me {
  D value;
  void mistake1 () { value[0] = 0; }
  void mistake2 () { mistake1(value); }
  // and a bajillion other member functions...
};
```

And, given that I know in advance the finite set of possible template parameters (let's say `int` and `float` here), I just want to make sure they at least compile while I'm working.

Now I can do this, which obviously falls short:

```
int main () {
  test_me<int> i;
  test_me<float> f;
}
```

Since `mistake1` and `mistake2` aren't generated, the code compiles fine despite the indexed access attempt to a non-array type, and the incorrect function call.

So what I've been doing during development is just writing code that calls all the member functions:

```
template <typename D> static void testCalls () {
    test_me<D> t;
    t.mistake1();
    t.mistake2();
    // and so on... so many mistakes...
}

int main () {
   testCalls<int>();
   testCalls<float>();
}
```

But this gets to be a pain, especially when the member functions start to have complex side effects or preconditions, or require nontrivial parameters, or have non-public members and not-yet-developed friends. So, I'd like a way to test compilation without having to explicitly call everything (and, ideally, I'd like to be able to test compilation without modifying any "test" code *at all* as I add new members).

So my question is: With at least GCC 9, **is there a way to force (potentially temporarily) the compiler to generate code for a template class's entire set of members, given template parameters?**

Comment: Declare a set of (member) function pointers for them, and instantiate these.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That's not a bad idea. Actually I found it's even simpler after playing around with it; you don't even need to declare the pointer types, you can just take the function addresses: https://ideone.com/eq5qtV Still -- I wonder if there's a way to do it without having to maintain a corresponding list of `&members`.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. This is during development of e.g. header-based template library code.

Comment: Write a unit test for your function. If you don't have one, you should not have the function in the first place. Write it **together** with the function.

Comment: @JasonC Well the idea is to declare a _type trait_ class for `T`, that you can check at a certain point with number of `static_assert`s. This will make error messages better readable an you can point out what exactly is missing from `T` even if no other code tries to instantiate that funciton.

Comment: Reflection and reification will make this possible.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont !!! Is [N4766](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/n4766.pdf) being considered? I haven't been keeping up on my C++ news. Oh man, it's going to be great, and it's going to be nightmarishly misused too. It'll be like... Java is a country that's never had a minimum drinking age, and C++ is a country where it used to be 21 and suddenly it's legal for everyone. If that analogy makes sense.  (Qt land might get weird, too.)

Comment: @JasonC https://www.infoworld.com/article/3528882/c-plus-plus-20-spec-finalized-c-plus-plus-23-spec-begins.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just **explicitly** instantiate the class:

```
template struct test_me<int>;
template struct test_me<float>;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cv3zrE)

Comment: Ah! I suspected it was something simple that I already knew how to do, but I couldn't connect the dots. Awesome, thanks.

Comment: @JasonC Note a caveat for this solution: your member functions must defined *before* the explicit instantiation, otherwise those definitions are not guaranteed to be instantiated. [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Goa57q). If your testing code is sure to be after all the definitions of your class members, then this solution will work, but it's something worth bearing in mind.

Comment: @cigien Another caveat is that this won't instantiate member templates (which is expected, I guess, but it's not a catch-all solution). At the end of the day I needed a combination of this answer *and* [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65498567/616460) to cover member templates. This is a rare occasion when I wish I could mark both answers as correct. I hope you didn't take the check mark switch personally; blame it on the system. :)

Comment: You have indeed to (explicitly) instantiate members template too (`template void test_me<int>::foo<char>();`).

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is not allowed by the language, at least with implicit instantiations of your test class. When you implicitly instantiate `test_me` with some type, the definitions of the member functions are not allowed to be implicitly instantiated, as per [temp.inst#11](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.inst#11):

> An implementation **shall not** implicitly instantiate a function template, a variable template, a member template, **a non-virtual member function**, a member class or static data member of a templated class, or a substatement of a constexpr if statement ([stmt.if]), unless such instantiation is required.

So if you want to implicitly instantiate all the `mistake` member functions, you have no choice but to require their instantiation somehow. As in your example with `testCalls`, you can make calls to those member functions, or you can ODR-use them some other way, such as taking their addresses.

Comment: Darn. Couldn't be any clearer though. Thanks for pulling that up. Taking the addresses seems to be a decent option ([example](https://ideone.com/eq5qtV)).

Comment: @JasonC Yeah, it may seem unfortunate, but there are actually very good reasons for this constraint (feature?). And yes, I think taking their addresses is a nice way of expressing that you want those member functions to be instantiated.